# Use API data to ensure current product prices in database data then sort by price

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, join

Because I've waited until now to bother learning the magical JSON functions that modern MYSQL affords, I wonder if my code is optimally written and if there are cautions/limitations to be aware of.

My script uses PHP to pass API-borne data to a MYSQL query where it is LEFT JOINed with locally stored product data.

The task is to update the prices coming from the stored data then sort by the updated prices.  (What happens with the data after that is ...anyone's guess.)

Context: [Map and replace product prices from one 2d array to another 2d array then sort by updated prices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76144270/2943403)

Sample Data as part of a MCVE: https://phpize.online/s/oC (full, realistic payload is not available)

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT prod.product_sku,
       prod.product_type,
       prod.contact_name,
       prod.phone,
       COALESCE(api.full_price, prod.full_price) AS full_price,
       prod.product_name,
       prod.product_id,
       prod.rating
FROM products AS prod
LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(
         ?,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
                  product_sku INT PATH '$.product_sku',
                  full_price VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.full_price'
         )
     ) AS api ON prod.product_sku = api.product_sku
ORDER BY full_price
SQL;

var_export(
     $mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$json])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
);
```